# Template implementation for commutative operators, legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I've tried to implement a commutative addition operator for one of my classes:

```
struct mytype
{
    constexpr mytype(othertype const &);
    constexpr mytype operator+(othertype const &rhs) const;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto operator+(T const &lhs, mytype const &rhs) -> decltype(rhs + lhs)
{
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

The idea is that anything accepted on the right hand side also becomes acceptable on the left hand side as long as the right hand side is a `mytype`.

This works fine with icc and Visual Studio, and goes into an endless recursion resolving the `decltype` on gcc and clang (terminated when the maximum template depth is reached).

I can see that the endless recursion might in fact be more correct, as explained in the [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40988): the specialization is needed before overload resolution takes place (because it is an input to overload resolution).

On the other hand the commercial compilers somehow manage (whether by accident or on purpose is probably debatable).

What is the correct behavior here?

Is it possible to avoid specifying a full list of classes for which `operator+` is supposed to be commutative?

Compilable example:

```
struct othertype {};

struct mytype
{
    constexpr mytype() : value(1) { }
    constexpr mytype(int v) : value(v) { }
    constexpr mytype(othertype const &o) : value(2) { }     // 1

    constexpr mytype operator+(mytype const &rhs) const
    {
        return mytype(value + rhs.value);
    }
    constexpr mytype operator+(othertype const &rhs) const  // 2
    {
        return mytype(value + 2);
    }

    int value;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto operator+(T const &lhs, mytype const &rhs) -> decltype(rhs + lhs)
{
    return rhs + lhs;
}

void test()
{
    constexpr mytype mine;
    constexpr othertype other;

    constexpr auto result = other + mine;

    static_assert(result.value == 3);
}
```

The problem goes away when the conversion `// 1` is removed, which isn't helpful in my use case. The separate addition operator `// 2` is not sufficient to help resolve the `decltype`: overload resolution should have picked that up, but the problem happens before overload resolution.

The infinite recursion happens after specializing the template for `T = othertype`: converting `othertype` to `mytype` gives an addition expression with `mytype` on both sides, which again can be resolved through the template (even though a non-template exists).

Comment: How do you use this operator? Could you perhaps show us a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you have? Even if we can't replicate the problem, it could be useful to see how you use it. And it could be very useful to see your implementation of the member overload, and what `othertype` is.

Comment: By the way, do you really need to non-explicit conversion operator? What happens if you remove it or make it `explicit`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this is part of a refactoring — `mytype` is supposed to replace `othertype` in the long run, so it needs to be convertible to allow gradually replacing instances without breaking the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You might restrict your template with SFINAE to discard `operator+<mytype>(mytype const &lhs, mytype const &rhs)`:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, mytype>::value, int>::type = 0>
constexpr auto operator+(T const &lhs, mytype const &rhs) -> decltype(rhs + lhs)
{
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fef8fba2ab4a31b)